# Dynamically redefine add and remove methods of events

Tags: c#, events, reflection

I have something like that :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected void ToDoOnAdd()
    {

    }

    protected void ToDoOnRemove()
    {

    }
}

public class TopClass : BaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler OnEvent;
}
```

What I would like to do is to call the method `ToDoOnAdd` each time `OnEvent += ...` is called and `ToDoOnRemove` when `OnEvent -= ...` is called, and that for each events defined in classes derived from `BaseClass`.

I know that I can do something like :

```
public class TopClass : BaseClass
{
    private event EventHandler onEvent;

    public event EventHandler OnEvent
    {
        add
        {
            onEvent += value;
            ToDoOnAdd();
        }
        remove
        {
            onEvent -= value;
            ToDoOnRemove();
        }
    }
}
```

but I would like to find a solution to do this dynamically so I (or other developpers using BaseClass) don't have to do this for each events.

Is there a way to use reflection in the constructor of `BaseClass`?

```
   public BaseClass()
    {
        var events = this.GetType().GetEvents();
        foreach (var ev in events)
        {
            ???
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!